# Admob not updating Impressions/Clicks after uploading it on playstore

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I had created a banner admob ad using [this link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start). App it was working good. I even got publisher id and I was able to view impressions and clicks from [Admob website](https://apps.admob.com/#home). But after I completed the development, I uploaded the app on play store and i am not able to view any ads impression/clicks from [Admob website](https://apps.admob.com/#home) though ads are showing inside the app downloaded from playstore. I have linked the app from playstore. Around 50 people have downloaded the app and it has been 3 days but no update in Impressions/clicks.
Now what I need to do to be able to track impressions or clicks. Do I need to get a new publisher ID? If so what are the steps to obtain it. Thanks in advance. Help me I'm new in admob. If you need code then I'll post that as well in the question.

I am using this code in the activities where I want to show the ad

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Do I need to modify this code? I

Comment: You need to change your `publisher ID` which linked to you account in `strings.xml` as official doc provided [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#give_your_app_an_ad_unit_id).

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640814/admob-impressions-clicks-not-updating-after-uploading-it-on-playstore